# Open links from embedded visualforce page on new window

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Right now I have a custom vf page on my details, that contains two related lists (Activity Histories and Open Activities) in two different tabs. The problem is that when I click a link, it opens a new window inside that section. I would like to open in a new window. Here is my VF Page (with script that I tried to put working):

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ActivitiesAndHistoryRelatedListExtension">

        <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="theTabPanel" style="height:300px">
        <apex:tab label="Atividades abertas" name="name1" id="tabOne">

            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width:100%;height:150px;">
                <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="OpenActivities" > 
                    <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value=""/></apex:facet> 
                </apex:relatedList>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Histórico de atividades" name="name2" id="tabTwo">

            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width:100%;height:150px;">
                <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="ActivityHistories" > 
                    <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value=""/></apex:facet>  
                </apex:relatedList>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

       $("a[href^=http]").each(function(){
          for(i=0; i<excludes.length; i++) {
             if(this.href.indexOf(excludes[i]) != -1) {
                return true; // continue each() with next link
             }
          }

          if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {

               // attach a do-nothing event handler to ensure we can 'trigger' a click on this link
               $(this).click(function() { return true; }); 

               $(this).attr({
                   target: "_blank",
                   title: "Opens in a new window"
               });

               $(this).click(); // trigger it
          }    }) });
        </script > 
</apex:page>
```

But no matter what I do, it always open inside the section, like the example:

[image]

Anyone have any ideia how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I do not see jquery being loaded in your vf page include the below line

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"/>
```

2) If you want to open link in a different window all you need to look for all a tags and set attribute to blank (

**NOTE:** You can adjust the href that needs to be redirected based on your need, I have set the code to redirect all hrefs to a new window.

```
<script >
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j('a').attr("target","_blank");
});
</script >
```

Comment: Superb! Really nice code, and works really well! Thanks!